# What's the best solution for "Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed?"

Tags: swift, swiftui, publish-subscribe

After looking through other posts and Apple doc on this, I can't find a tidy solution that even compiles.

I would think my situation is typical: My app does queries over a network asynchronously, gets results, and then stores those results in published variables of an observable object so my SwiftUI reflects them.

I do this by creating a Query object, which stores success and failure handlers as closures. After the query is executed and a result comes back, the appropriate handler is called and will typically update an observed class member. That's where the error is flagged (here the observed member is currUser):

[image]

This currUser member lives in an object that serves the role of viewmodel, of class UserManager.

```
class UserManager : ObservableObject
{
    @Published var currUser: User?
    @Published var lastError: NetError?
    ...
}
```

It gets passed into my SwiftUI view in a structure:

```
struct StartupView: View
{
    @ObservedObject var userMgr: UserManager

    init(withManagement: Management)
    {
        userMgr = withManagement.userMgr
    }
    ...
}
```

I can't find any accepted place to put receive(on:) as suggested by the error message. Trying to do so on userMgr here isn't valid.

So then I tried making UserManager a @MainActor, but this creates further errors in its methods:

[image]

And if I try to address that by changing the signatures of the handler closures to be MainActors, more errors are propagated:

[image]

The only solution I've found that works is to add DispatchQueue thus:

```
func userLoadedFromDB(user: User)
{
    print("User loaded from DB: \(user)")
    // Always have to change published variables on the main thread.
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.currUser = user
    }
}
```

But it seems hokey and error-prone to have to remember to put this everywhere that a published variable might get changed. Is this really my best option?

Given that this entire idiom seems to cater to asynchronous activities and observing a data model, I wonder why the publishing system doesn't just automatically publish on the main thread. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Annotate `class UserManager` with `@MainActor`. Then, at least the compiler will warn you when there's Swift concurrency code that accesses a property or function outside of the `@MainActor`. That said, it won't warn you if you access it in a Combine chain or callback function that doesn't conform to Swift concurrency practices. Watching all of the WWDC information on concurrency would be an informative step in learning more about how this works.

Comment: Thanks. I did try that, but it caused a cascade of errors (I described this in the post). I'm not using Combine, for what that's worth.

Comment: Definitely recommend watching the WWDC videos so that you can understand how to take care of those errors

Comment: You are mixing old and new you either use MainActor or DispatchQueue.main and convert any completion handlers to use async/await if you use MainActor

Comment: you would be better returning results from your async funcs then you wouldn't need any objects at all.

Comment: Thanks guys. @malhal The functions that do the data-fetching are async, as in loadUserFromDB() above. Not sure what the "wouldn't need any objects" refers to.

Comment: edit: you would be better returning results from your async funcs into `@State` then you wouldn't need any observable objects at all, so wouldn't even get the publishing changes error because wouldn't be using `@Published`.

Comment: Storing a bunch of stuff in the UI isn't generally good design though. There's all kinds of things that are going on in the background independent of the UI, but which the UI might need to reflect. The big question here is why @Published variables don't publish their changes on the main thread automatically, since that is required.

Comment: `@Published` can be used outside of a `ObservableObject`. It is not _always_ required that they publish on the main thread.

Comment: @jnpdx That's not what the error message says: "Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed."

Comment: Yes, publishing changes to `View`s is not allowed. You can use `@Published` outside of an `ObservableObject`.

Comment: @Oscar State isn't UI (and neither are View structs actually, once you learn how they are diffed to create/update UIKit Views).

Comment: Thanks guys. Info from Apple now indicates that all of this is going to be obsolete and we should use the "Observation framework," which I thought I was. But no; Apple is now piling yet another paradigm onto this mess, and doing so with macros. They're churning out one incomplete, contradictory framework after another, and it is wasting a monumental amount of dev time.